# Searching for bingo with SQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have a mysql database with a table with 50000 bingo plates.

The table structure:

```
plade_line_id  plade_id  number1  number2  number3  number4  number5
1              1         62       82       52       85       73
2              1         26       24       67       81       99
3              1         5        69       17       52       84
4              2         62       82       52       85       73
5              2         26       24       67       81       99
6              2         5        69       17       52       84
```

My idea is to add numbers to an array as they are drawn.
And then somehow get the plade_id when there is(A statement for each?):

1. 1 Line on same plate
2. 2 Lines on same plate
3. 3 Lines on same plate

The plate is 5x3 and you can only win on the above conditions.
On one plate, a single number can only be there one time.
And the numbers are between 1-99.

I only need like 2 or 3 plade_id's, so the result should be something like:

```
plade_id
6267    
21347
43295
```

I am not really sure how to go about this, so any help will be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Please show us the result that you expect.

Comment: You got HTML in the table? You should fix this!

Comment: The HTML is just to show how the table is setup :)

Comment: Simply put the data in proper columns, no html is needed.

Comment: You have to define the "Searching for bingo" part. What is the size of your bingo grid (5x5 or 5x3)? 5x5 bingo has multiple win condition : The line, The row, The diagonal, The post stamp, The diamond, The 4 corners, The Zoro. And many others that may depends on region or casino.

Comment: For the 5x3: You want the plade_id where number1   is in the drawned and number 2 is drawned  etc.

Comment: @DragandDrop updated.
I only need the plade_id, when it matches one of the three win conditions.

Comment: "one of the three win conditions." , if numbers are dawn one by one how can condition 2 and 3 be satisfy before condition one?

Comment: They can't. But I don't need a plade_id if it has 1 complete line and 2 more numbers on two different lines. So basally when there are 5 matches on a row on one plate, 10 matches on two rows on one plate, 15 matches on three rows on one plate.

Comment: So using my answer you will have all completed lines, counting the number of completed lines having the same plade_id should be trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Naïve approach, will be to simply stack IN clause:
Without modification of the table, we can check if the number1, number2 etc are all in the numbers drawn.

```
;with Plades as
(
select 1 plade_line_id, 1 plade_id, 62 number1, 82 number2, 52 number3, 85 number4, 1 number5    union
select 2, 1, 26, 24, 67, 81, 2   union
select 3, 1, 5, 69, 17, 52, 3    union
select 4, 2, 62, 82, 52, 85, 4   union
select 5, 2, 26, 24, 67, 81, 5   union
select 6, 2, 5, 69, 17, 52, 6    
),
Drawn as (
Select 62 Number    union
Select 82    union
Select 52    union
Select 85    union
Select 4     union
Select 81    
)
select * from Plades
WHERE 
      number1 IN (SELECT Number FROM Drawn)
  AND number2 IN (SELECT Number FROM Drawn)
  AND number3 IN (SELECT Number FROM Drawn)
  AND number4 IN (SELECT Number FROM Drawn)
  AND number5 IN (SELECT Number FROM Drawn)
```

If you allow modification of your table, perhaps a hash on the ordered { number1 to number6} could be usefull.

But the best thing will be to work a smaller set: the bingo card that are currently beeing play in the room.

The reason is simple, the first winner is expected at turn 42-43. 
Each number drawn, you will search into : 
 `50000 bingo plates x Number of lines on a bingo plates`

Finding the 1 line, 2 lines.. plades is now trivial.
EG for 2 lines :

```
select plade_id, COUNT(*) as nbLines from Plades
WHERE 
      number1 IN (SELECT Number FROM Drawned)
  AND number2 IN (SELECT Number FROM Drawned)
  AND number3 IN (SELECT Number FROM Drawned)
  AND number4 IN (SELECT Number FROM Drawned)
  AND number5 IN (SELECT Number FROM Drawned)
GROUP BY plade_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Comment: This does work for 1 Line on the same plate, thanks a lot.

How would I then be able to get the plade_id, when there are two lines on the same plate and after, get when there is full plate?

Comment: `Select plade_id, count(*) [...] having  count(*) = 2`

Comment: Thanks, did it with GROUP BY plade_id HAVING COUNT(*) = 2